# Powershell Start-Process pnputil.exe

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run pnputil with start-process, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a script that works without start-process:

```
$Driver = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot" -Recurse -Filter "*inf"

$InstallDriver = foreach ($item in $Driver) {
          
PNPUtil.exe /add-driver $item.FullName /install

}
```

But if I'm doing the same with start-process I cant get it to work :

```
$Driver = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot" -Recurse -Filter "*inf"

$InstallDriver = foreach ($item in $Driver) {
          
Start-Process PNPUtil.exe /add-driver $item.FullName /install

}
```

I have also tried

```
Start-Process PNPUtil -ArgumentList '/add-driver $item.FullName /install'

Start-Process PNPUtil -ArgumentList '/add-driver "$item.FullName" /install'

Start-Process PNPUtil -ArgumentList '/add-driver "${$item.FullName}" /install'

Start-Process PNPUtil -ArgumentList "/add-driver "${$item.FullName}" /install'

Start-Process PNPUtil -ArgumentList "/add-driver $item.FullName} /install"
```

But it doesn't work

Does anyone know why it does not work?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

They are all separate arguments. Single quotes around variables will prevent the variable from expanding plus if you enclose `$variable.property` in double quotes you need a subexpression `$()`. Instead, try this

```
Start-Process PNPUtil -ArgumentList "/add-driver",$item.FullName,"/install"
```

Comment: Hi Doug Maurer and thanks for your help Unfortunately it does not work either. There is just a black box for each .inf file and I can see that its the help text for pnputil, so the arguments are still wrong

Comment: Worked in my testing. Do you still have quotes around the item?

Comment: I found a solution. there are spaces in some of the file names, so if I use
-ArgumentList "/add-driver `"$($item.FullName)`" /install" it works. 
Thanks for the help